# Getting current page url in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, url, jquery-mobile

I am trying to get the current page url in a jquery mobile site. (I am using the default ajax navigation).

My current attempt is this (binding to pagecreate) but doesnt work on any page injected into the DOM.

```
$( '[data-role=page]' ).live( 'pagecreate',function(){
  $('#site-toggle').attr('href',"http://" + location.host.replace('m.','') + window.location.pathname); 
});
```

Anyone know what I am missing?

A.

Answer (score 11):

Isn't this you are looking for:

```
var currentUrl = $.mobile.activePage.data('url');
```

Answer (score 4):

jQuery Mobile has a URL parsing method called `$.mobile.path.parseUrl`. It's use would be something like this:

```
var obj = $.mobile.path.parseUrl("http://jblas:password@mycompany.com:8080/mail/inbox?msg=1234");
```

Which would return the following object:

```
//  obj.href:         http://jblas:password@mycompany.com:8080/mail/inbox?msg=1234&type=unread#msg-content
//  obj.hrefNoHash:   http://jblas:password@mycompany.com:8080/mail/inbox?msg=1234&type=unread
//  obj.hrefNoSearch: http://jblas:password@mycompany.com:8080/mail/inbox
//  obj.domain:       http://jblas:password@mycompany.com:8080
//  obj.protocol:     http:
//  obj.authority:    jblas:password@mycompany.com:8080
//  obj.username:     jblas
//  obj.password:     password
//  obj.host:         mycompany.com:8080
//  obj.hostname:     mycompany.com
//  obj.port:         8080
//  obj.pathname:     /mail/inbox
//  obj.directory:    /mail/
//  obj.filename:     inbox
//  obj.search:       ?msg=1234&type=unread
//  obj.hash:         #msg-content
```

Your code would change to something like this:

```
$( '[data-role=page]' ).live( 'pagecreate',function(){
    var $.mobile.path.parseUrl(window.location.href);
    $('#site-toggle').attr('href', obj.protocol + '//' + obj.host + obj.pathname + obj.search + obj.hash); 
});
```

Documentation can be found here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0rc2/docs/api/methods.html

Comment: This works on chrome but not my android. Any idea why?

`$('#site-toggle').live('tap', function () {
url = $.mobile.path.parseUrl("http://" + window.location.host.replace('m.','') + window.location.pathname); 
window.location.href=url.href;
});`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$.mobile.urlHistory.getActive().url
```

It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the [jQuery-URL-Parser](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) plugin?

```
var url = $.url(); //retrieves current url
```

You can also get specific parts of the URL like this:

```
var file = $.url.attr("file");
var path = $.url.attr("path");
var host = $.url.attr("host");
...
```

If you need to get Querystring parameters:

```
var parm = $.url.param("id");
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want this

```
$(location).attr('pathname');
```

You should read [this article](http://tech-blog.maddyzone.com/javascript/get-current-url-javascript-jquery)